# How to get image URL from WebView

Tags: android, webview

Im trying to get a url to an image that is displayed in WebView.
This is my code. The completely task is to get url and display picture in imageView.
Some troubles with AsyncTask is not a big trouble.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView imgView;
    TextView txtUrl;
    String url;
    Drawable mPict;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

         WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         url = "http://webuycontent.atwebpages.com/wallbase.html";

        txtUrl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        return Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(), "src");
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... parameter) {
            try {
                mPict =  grabImageFromUrl(url);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                txtUrl.setText("Error: " + e);
            }

            return "Str";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            imgView.setImageDrawable(mPict);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what do want to achieve exactly!

Comment: overrid webview methods

Comment: Are able to retrieve the url successfully?

Comment: @goonerdroid i need to get image URL from http://webuycontent.atwebpages.com/wallbase.html

Comment: You must know the structure of the page that you are trying to load! Do you?

Comment: @Garf1eld instead of creating async tasks to load image from URL just use this library which can async download images https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a pattern of image url or image name for this particular site, you can parse HTML code of the page and find image you want. You can use HttpClient to obtain page' html code.

There is no general way to get image from web page.